# Jenkins HTML Publisher always absolute?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Hi everyone I am trying to publish my html reports in jenkins but the problem I am facing is that my reports for each run are generate inside a folder and folder's name is always the given as the Timestamp. So, ho can I give dynamic directory path in HTML publisher?

Comment: did you find an answer by now? I am having the same problem